# How to get notified when an input was set

Tags: angular

I got a master-detail implementation written with angular2, it's working fine and all is well in the valley. The issue is, that I have an @Input in my details component. the master fills it with the right object, but when clicking another object, I have ui "residues" from the former object.

How can an object react (how can I write an event handler of some sort) to react to a "set" event on that input? can this even be done (the goal here is to bring the ui to the initial state, but will be good for other purposes as well I guess)?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child-setter

```
@Input() set name(name: string) {
    this._name = (name && name.trim()) || '<no name set>';
    // or do other stuff
}
get name() { return this._name; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can also use the OnChanges lifecycle hook:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#onchanges

Comment: `OnChanges` is only called when the input was updated by an updated Angular binding, while for a setter it works no matter how the property was updated. Depending on the requirements one or the other is the better choice.